# Metric on a quotient space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space and $\sim$ is a closed relation on $X$. That is $x_n\sim y_n$, $x_n\to x$, $y_n\to y$ implies $x\sim y$. Then the quotient space $X/\sim$ is compact Hausdorff and in fact metrizable.

> Is the Hausdorff metric on equivalence classes $[x]\in X/\sim$ which are compact subsets of $X$ a metric compatible with the topology of $X/\sim$?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is no and I have a simple counterexample.

Let $X=([0,1]\times [0,1])\cup([1,2]\times\{0\})\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a square with a segment attached to it. Let $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $\pi(x,y)=x$ be the orthogonal projection onto the first coordinate so $\pi:X\to [0,2]$ is a surjection and $[0,2]$ is a quotient space $X/\sim$ with $a\sim b$ defined by $f(a)=f(b)$. However, the equivalence classes $\pi^{-1}(t)$ of this relation are segments if $0\leq t\leq 1$ and points if $1<t\leq 2$ so $\pi^{-1}(1+2^{-n})$ (singleton) does not converge to $\pi^{-1}(1)$ (segment of length one) in the Hausdorff metric.

Comment: Why it doesn't converge? Distance between those points and a segment tends to zero, right?

Comment: @pem The Hausdorff distance between $\{(1 + 2^{-n},0)\}$ and $\{1\} \times [0,1]$ is larger than $1$, it is given by the distance between $(1,1)$ and $(1 + 2^{-n},0)$.

Comment: Yes, now I see it.

Comment: Nice simple example. You're probably aware of it, but I'll mention it just in case: The topology induced by the Hausdorff distance is finer than the quotient topology, hence they coincide if, and only if, the topology induced by the Hausdorff distance is compact.